# Windows start-up application order

Tags: windows-vista, boot

Does anyone know how can I choose the order in which my Windows Vista start-up application are started? For example, I wish for my antivirus to start before Outlook or any instant messaging programs.

Comment: Your question is very similar to this: http://superuser.com/questions/48092/getting-startup-programs-to-start-serially. Maybe it can help.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to postpone the startup of **services** in Vista, is to go to Administration Tools / Services, double-click on the service, and in the properties dialog change its Startup type to "Automatic (Delayed Start)", then OK.

If that's not enough flexibility, you can use [Startup Delayer](http://www.r2.com.au/software.php?page=2&show=startdelay):

> Startup Delayer allows you to setup
>   how many seconds after Windows has
>   started, to load each program.

However, I must remark that personally I don't recommend monkeying too much with your startup order.

Answer (score 0):

[startupdelayer](http://www.jockersoft.com/english/startupdelayer_index.php) can set a timed, rather than an ordered delay.